# In a plane crash who died?

Tags: lateral-thinking, english, situation

In a plane crash somewhere, every single person died but two people survived.

How is this possible?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a very well known riddle...

Comment: https://xkcd.com/169/

Answer (score 8):

The 2 survivors were:

> a couple, and the only two that were in a relationship. Every single (in the relationship sense) was killed.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the other answers, it's possible the two survivors were:

> Siamese twins. Since their bodies are linked, they are one "person", but also not a "single person" since there are two of them.

Answer (score 4):

> Anyone who was married survived. "Every single person" can either be interpreted as "all of the people" or "every non-married person."

Comment: Wouldn't people who were dating survive as well? Since they wouldn't be considered single?

Comment: In legal definitions for interpersonal status, a single person is someone who is not in a relationship or is unmarried. So, technically they wouldn't be single.

Comment: It is a political incorrect question. Possibly nowadays the most relevant is the status published on facebook :-)